# What happens if the person who used the Wizz credits on a booking can’t take the flight?

Tags: europe, wizz-air

I have a couple of wizz credits due to a flight that got cancelled quite a while back. I want to make a new booking using these Wizz credits with a couple of my friends but I might not be able to take the flight due to personal issues.

If I am the person that paid this flight with Wizz credits and I am the owner of the account that needs to be present, what will happen if I won’t be able to show up? Will my friends be denied and won’t be able to fly because of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, if you make a new booking and you select Wizz air credits as payment then the website won’t allow you to complete the booking unless you are one of the passengers too while you book online.

Of course, if you then decide not to travel is up to you but then it would be just 4 passengers max (excluding you but the booking itself has to include you anyway). This would be a bit of a waste of Wizz credits though since you would not be travelling as per the question.

It is a strange policy but then again this is a low cost airline so it is to be expected for them to be reluctant / difficult when it comes to get any money back in the form of vouchers like Wizz credits or similar.

See below:

> WIZZ Credits may be used for payments of reservations including no more, than 5 Passengers, where the WIZZ Account owner is one of the Passengers included in the reservation. Wizz Credit may be used for modifications of existing reservations as well.

[Wizz credits conditions](https://wizzair.com/static/docs/default-source/downloadable-documents/wizz-account-terms-and-conditions_211210_final_en_gb_2fbd07ad.pdf)

Comment: This quote from the Wizz Credit Conditions doesn't fully answer the OP's question. The words "...the Wizz account owner **is one of the passengers..."** can be read to require the account owner to be physically present and taking the flight.

Comment: The answer is the whole text I wrote, not just the quote which is there just for context. I never meant to “answer with a quote”, hence why I wrote an answer and not just a quote. 

In my answer I explained that what happens is that the OP has to be on of the passengers in the online booking but the OP does not necessarily have to travel. This was the OP doubt and I think I cleared it for the OP with my answer. It’s quite confusing the way Wizz air writes it in the conditions so it’s not easy to understand first time.

Comment: @AlejandroRamónFernández, can you add how you know that the rest of the party can travel without the owner of the account?

Comment: Sure @Willeke : from the quote where it says in their conditions “ where the WIZZ Account owner is one of the Passengers included in the reservation” that is where I know you only need to be in the reservation, not necessarily travel. That’s why I think it’s a waste if the OP is not travelling himself/herself…